# Calling an audio import using variable (REACT/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio

So I have started writing my app, which is a simple music compositor and I have got 9 different local audio files. After a particular div is used, different sound is being played. I could use switch(case), however I believe there could be better solution to estimate, which type of the sound should be played at the moment.

My code looks like:

```
import Drum1 from `./audio/Drum1.mp3`;
import Drum2 .......;
```

and below I've got a function which calls to play a particular sound

```
playMusic() {
for(let i=0;i<this.state.items;i++) {
 let instrument = this.state.instrumentName[i]; // Drum1, Drum2, Drum1 etc
 let audio = new Audio (#####); 
 audio.play();
}
```

so the problem is that if I write i.e.

```
let audio = new Audio (Drum1);
```

the function works, however, if I want to use a variable to call it:

```
let audio = new Audio (instrument) - which is `Drum1`
```

it doesn't work.

Any ideas what's wrong or how should I correct it?

Comment: What are the values of this.state.instrumentName and how are you setting those? You are  iterating over items and getting instrument from state.instrumentName. Also your for loop doesn't have length.

Comment: this.state.instrumentName is an array with names of the instruments going to be played. Depending on the users choice it could be i.e. ['Drum1','Drum3','Piano2',...]; 

Length of the loop is dependent on the number of instruments (this.state.items) included by user

Comment: ['Drum1','Drum3','Piano2',...]; is storing strings while you need imported object in new Audio. So perhaps they should be [Drum1,Drum3...];

Comment: Sorted it. Thanks!